# inserting a string to a set of structs (which in turn has a set of strings)

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, set

This is my struct:

```
struct album_details {
    string album;
    set <string> artist;
    set <string> album_songs;
};
```

and this is my data structure

```
set <album_details> musicinformation;
```

I am trying to insert song names into this set but I get an error. What am I missing out on?

```
musicinformation.insert (load_info.album_songs.insert ("No tears left to cry"));
```

This is what I have written.

Comment: What error do you get? What is `load_info`? Where is a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to insert the result of

```
load_info.album_songs.insert ("No tears left to cry")
```

into a set containing `album_details`. If you look [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert) you will see that no version of `insert` will return an `album_details`. You need to rethink how you are doing this. Namely something like:

```
album_details details;
details.album_songs.insert ("No tears left to cry")
load_info.insert(details);
```